# Remove comment author link wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, comments, genesis

i have **Genesis Magazine Pro Theme** and i want to delete comment author link.

I use many different guide:

http://wpsquare.com/remove-comment-author-website-link-wordpress/

https://www.engagewp.com/remove-wordpress-comment-author-link/

I add some code in functions.php, but these method doesn't work

I have still remove the field link when someone post a comment, but now i want to remove the **comment author link**.

How to resolve it?

For example, i want to remove the link on "*Mr Wordpress*".

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case that you don't want to do it directly on Genesis, you can paste this filter at the end of your theme functions.php file:

```
function filter_get_comment_author_url( $url, $id, $comment ) {
    return "";
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url', 'filter_get_comment_author_url', 10, 3);
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to:

genesis > lib > structure > comments.php

And find the following line:

```
if ( ! empty( $url ) && 'http://' !== $url ) {$author = sprintf( '%s', esc_url( $url ), genesis_attr( 'comment-author-link' ), $author );}
```

And replace it with this new:

```
if ( ! empty( $url ) && 'http://' !== $url ) {$author = sprintf($author );}
```

Comment: i think it's a different thing. I update my answer with more specific information. thank you ScyGeek

Comment: wow it works!!! But in this way, if in future i update genesis, it returns back on default state. There is a way to implement in other ways? :)